concatenating a new string from variables in an appsettings.json file and DateTime
I have a Selenium test where I am filling in a web form.  The test works but as part of the test validation I currently call a method to return a string multiple times.
//Variables stored in appsettings.json file
string ServiceName = _configuration[Configuration.EnvConfig + ":NewService"];
string VendorName = _configuration[Configuration.EnvConfig + ":NewVendor"];
string RelationshipManager = _configuration[Configuration.EnvConfig + ":RelationshipManager"];

// Date is stored in configuration class so that it can be passed to other class files for validation
private static string thisDay = Configuration.currentDate.ToString();

        public string NewVendorName()
        {
            string NewVendorName = thisDay + VendorName;
            return NewVendorName;
        }

        public string NewServiceName()
        {
            string NewServiceName = thisDay + ServiceName;
            return NewServiceName;
        }

I use these two methods in the majority of my tests and am calling them in multiple methods within those tests as part of my validation.
I've tried using a get set but have not been able to get that to work because of the non-null values.
I also tried setting the strings coming from appsettings.json to 'private static' but get an error at runtime.
        //Variables stored in appsettings.json file
    private static string ServiceName = _configuration[Configuration.EnvConfig + ":NewService"];
    private static string VendorName = _configuration[Configuration.EnvConfig + ":NewVendor"];
    private static string RelationshipManager = _configuration[Configuration.EnvConfig + ":RelationshipManager"];

    // Date is stored in configuration class so that it can be passed to other class files for validation
    private static string thisDay = Configuration.currentDate.ToString();
    string NewVendorName = thisDay + VendorName;
    string NewServiceName = thisDay + ServiceName;

I am looking for insight on the best way to implement this without having to call the same two methods over and over but am at a loss.

Why is calling the methods a problem?  It sounds like you tried to turn them into properties, which really serves only to remove the () parentheses when invoking them but structurally nothing else really changes.  If that's the goal, what stops you from making them properties?  What is the actual problem being solved?

@David I wasn't sure if calling the method multiple times was going to cause slowness or if there was a better way to do it.  I will keep it how I have it, I figured it was worth looking into now so I didn't need to do a bunch of refactoring later. Thanks!

Access to a property is effectively calling a method (though the method call may be optimized away). Calling methods is pretty darn fast.
